# Write-Only Access to the Windows Event Log

Tags: security, windows-10, event-log

Is there a way to grant Write-Only access to the Windows Event Log? I see Read-only and Full Control. How can I restrict the Read access?

Also, I was trying to find a way using SDDL Strings, but they are tricky to generate.